Lost updates to DynamoDB map
I'm using the go sdk v2. The vast majority of the time updates go through just fine, but a handful of times I've noticed updates seemingly getting lost. The UpdateItem function does not return an error, and yet the item does not get updated.
I'm using the expression builder to update MyMap.MyMapKey, with MyMap being a map[string]SomeStruct which translates to an AttributeValueMemberM in ddb.
My question is this : does calling UpdateItem with that syntax update only that one map key, or does it replace the whole map ? To be clearer, would multiple parallel calls updating different keys under MyMap (For example an update on MyMap.One and another on MyMap.Two risk overwriting each other, or are they guaranteed to both independently succeed ?
From the doc I think they should succeed, but I'm at a loss on what's going on.
Thanks

Could you provide an example? I'm afraid the most relevant information - your update expression - is missing here. Is your update expression something like set #mymap.#one = :one? What do you pass as expression attribute names and values?

Pretty much yes. I've logged it now and this comes out : "ExpressionAttributesNames":{"#0":"MyMap", "#1": "MyKey"}, "ExpressionAttributesValues": {"#0": {"Value": {"Message": {"Value": "blah"}}}} and "UpdateExpression": "SET #0.#1 = :0\n"


My question is this : does calling UpdateItem with that syntax update only that one map key, or does it replace the whole map ? To be clearer, would multiple parallel calls updating different keys under MyMap (For example an update on MyMap.One and another on MyMap.Two risk overwriting each other, or are they guaranteed to both independently succeed ?

All singleton writes to DynamoDB are atomic and strongly serialised. For that reason there is no risk of concurrent updates manipulating your items to produce undesirable results.

Okay so something else is going on, thanks for confirming ! I'll keep debugging
